# Does the bitwise operator consume a large amount of resources?

Tags: erlang

In my erlang code, i have some `Bitwise` operation like `bor` or `band`.
such as:

```
(?SRVCC_3GPP_ALERTING_SUPPORT 
                    bor ?SRVCC_3GPP_PRE_ALERTING_SUPPORT 
                    bor ?SRVCC_3GPP_MID_CALL_SUPPORT) band Acc;
```

When i do system test, i find the cpu usage is higher than before.

So i doubt that is caused by `Bitwise`, but i am not very sure.

Anyone, who can tell me something about the cpu usage of `Bitwise` in erlang.
How to find some clue for this?

Comment: Assuming your program has more code in it than your snippet, try profiling your application and see what consumes resources more. http://erlang.org/doc/man/eprof.html

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are working on bignums of a very large size (like 2^2048), those operations should hardly be measureable compared to the rest of the work your program is doing.